# IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation API and IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3, identityserver4

I get the access token from the IdSrv4 and when i try to call my api with that token

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(token.AccessToken);
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:60602/api/users");
```

i get this error message:

> Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware
>   Error: 0 : Authentication failed System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Sequence contains no elements    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.DiscoveryDocumentIssuerSecurityTokenProvider.<RetrieveMetadata>b__1(JsonWebKey
>   key) in
>   c:\local\identity\server3\AccessTokenValidation\source\AccessTokenValidation\Plumbing\DiscoveryDocumentIssuerSecurityTokenProvider.cs:line
>   152    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() 
>   at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ResolveIssuerSigningKey(String
>   token, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityKeyIdentifier
>   keyIdentifier, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String
>   token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String
>   securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters,
>   SecurityToken& validatedToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat.Unprotect(String protectedText) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.d__0.MoveNext()

I read this issue and add certificate generated by this code 
https://github.com/ElemarJR/LearningIdentityServer4/tree/master/LearningIdentityServer.OAuth

but without success.

**WebApi code**
...

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
 app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
 JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
 app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
 {
       Authority = "http://localhost:5000",//Constants.BaseAddress,
       RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" },
 });
```

...

any suggestions ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/108 It seems there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem; Read following links
[enter link description here][1]

> [Identity server 4 token not validate in .NetFramework Api that use Identity Server 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760087/identity-server-4-token-not-validate-in-netframework-api-that-use-identity-serv?noredirect=1#comment68754258_40760087)

and

> https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/124

in teh summery you must upgrade identityserver3.accesstokenvalidation to " v2.13.0"