# Identity server 4 token not validate in .NetFramework Api that use Identity Server 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openid, identityserver3, identityserver4

In my identityserver app that use idsv4 and run on port "5000" have a client

```
            new Client
           {
            ClientId = "client",

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
        }`
```

and in my .Net Framework Api's startup class that use port no "7001" :

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
  Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
  ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,

        RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" }
    });`
```

and finally in my client catch token successfully:

```
    static TokenResponse GetClientToken()
    {
       var client = new TokenClient(
       "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
       "client",
       "secret");

    return client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1").Result;
}`
```

but when i use this token to call api:

```
static void CallApi(TokenResponse response)
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   client.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);

   Console.WriteLine(client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:7001/api/identity/get").Result);
}
```

client throw an exception:

Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
I have done all of them in core api and every things are ok!!

Comment: This is the accepted behavior, Your API should not allow tokens issued by unknown identity servers. Your API is registered against IdentityServer run on port 7000. So It will only accept token issued by that identity server.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "NetFramework Api that use Identity Server 3"?

Comment: an full .net framework api that use identity server3 token validation library

Comment: This was due to a bug that was fixed today: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/124

Comment: problem solved
thank you

Answer (score 1):

After switching to X509 certificate instead of the certificate that comes with the samples, everything started working fine.

Get rid of .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() and use .AddSigningCredential(GET_THE_CERT_FROM_YOUR_CERT_STORE)